# Printout using window.print() to different printers

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have two print buttons.

1) Print to "Kitchen"
2) Print to "bar"

The webpage which has data is a single page.

How can i tell the print command to take

1) printer installed in Kitchen when user selects Print to "Kitchen" and

2) take printer in bar when user selects "print to bar".

The data which needs to be printed will be different. For example

For kitchen i want to include first html table.
For Bar i want to include 2nd html table.

Hope it makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: Please can we see your current code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The webpage can not select what printer to be used. You can though, however, make an event happen when you click either button for specific styling.

Like, when you click on the "Kitchen" button you add a kitchen class to `<body>` that in the CSS means that the `<table>` is visible. But if you click the "Bar" button it removes the kitchen class and adds a bar class to `<body>` instead and the `<table>` is not visible.

Comment: If i connect printer to a local server and use some backend logic. Can this be done to solve this case?

Comment: Hmmm ... Maybe... If the backend has control of the printers you could probably create a job to print the content and by using parameters to the page know what printer the job is created for. What frameworks do you have available?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, according to the spec. The dialog that allows you to print is controlled entirely by the browser. You can customize your content that needs to be printed depending on which button is clicked, but choosing the printer has to be done by the user.